# Formula to determine X when closest to Y

Tags: formula

I need Infill_Profile_Size__c to display either '25', '40', '50' or '60' based on what is the closest to the number field Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c

so if Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c was 54.9 then Infill_Profile_Size__c would be '50', and 55 would display 60 etc.

I've tried multiple IF statements but am not getting anything to work.

Comment: are you looking into displaying only one of the 4 values based on the number entered in the other field ?

Comment: Yes, The result will either be 25/40/50/60 based on how close to Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c the number is

Comment: I tried to use this:       IF (AND(Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 0, Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c <= 32.4999), "25",
IF (AND(Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 32.5, Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c <= 44.999), "40",
IF (AND(Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 45, Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c <= 54.999), "50",
IF (AND(Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 55, Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 55),"60",
""))))         But, I got an error saying Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Number). (Related field: Formula).  These are all number fields however.

Comment: IF(Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 55, "60",
IF(Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 45, "50",
IF(Infill_Profile_Size_2nd__c >= 35, "40","25"
)))
This works but i'm at 5116 characters - Max is 5000  I had to change to text as the Formula return type.  Any pointers to reduce this size?

Comment: Just a heads-up: Putting things like code and formulas in the comments rarely works out very well because of the limited formatting options and number of characters. If someone asks you, in a comment, for more details, it's generally better to respond by making an [edit] to your question (and possibly making a comment saying you edited your question, and ask if any further clarification is needed).